# Connecting to HTTPS with netcat (nc)

Tags: http, https, openssl, netcat

I'm working on a homework assignment for my college course.
The task is to fetch web pages on HTTPS using [nc (netcat)](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/).

To fetch a page over HTTP, I can simply do the following:

```
cat request.txt | nc -w 5 <someserver> 80
```

In `request.txt` I have an HTTP 1.1 request

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: <someserver>
```

Now... This works perfectly fine. The challenge is, however - to fetch a web page that uses HTTPS?

I get a page certificate like this. And this is the point at which I'm currently stuck

```
openssl s_client -connect <someserver>:443
```

Comment: `socat - OPENSSL` would work, but that's probably not your assignment.

Comment: s/collage/college/, s/witch/which/

Comment: You can use bash redirection to avoid using `cat`, i.e. `nc  -w 5 <someserver> 80 < request.txt`.

Comment: See [What's the alternative to “nc -l” for HTTPS?](https://superuser.com/q/1470022/10136) for the other way around.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`nc` doesn't do https.  `openssl s_client` is as close as you'll get.  Do something like this:

```
$ cat request.txt | openssl s_client -connect server:443
```

Comment: I mean, unless your assignment is to write some code that does the SSL.  That would be StackOverflow territory :)

Comment: I've tried this, but I do not get what the server send back to me in stdout...

Comment: Add `-ign_eof` to also retrieve the response.

Answer (score 60):

**`ncat --ssl`**

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
printf 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: github.com\r\n\r\n' | ncat --ssl github.com 443
```

Same as on Super User [Can the telnet or netcat clients communicate over SSL?](https://superuser.com/questions/346958/can-the-telnet-or-netcat-clients-communicate-over-ssl) but `nmap` uses `ncat` with `nc` (e.g., `nc --ssl`).

On Debian or Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install ncat
```

Comment: is there any way to take your command and pass username and password commands into it for https sites that require authentication?

Comment: @user53029 I think not for most websites, where authentication works by filling a form and giving you a session cookies. Unless it is one of the very few websites that uses other methods of authentication like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication. You could also manually fill the form, and then send the cookie while it is valid. Or if you are desperate use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376189/how-to-login-into-a-website-with-casperjs

Comment: ncat is not nc, ncat does not support keep connection on send the payload like as nc. The question require a objetive response using nc not others apps.

Comment: @e-info128 thanks for that info. My philosophy is: when I google for something, and I click on this page, will I find the answer that I want.

Comment: what is `sudo apt-get install nmap`??

Comment: @AlexanderMills It's a package that includes a utility that works very much the same way as nc but has additional features. It's called ncat.

Comment: `ncat` is in its own separate Debian package, doesn't necessarily get installed along with nmap. We should `apt-get install ncat` not `nmap`, which just suggests `ncat`. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 8):

You probably want to use stunnel.

> A GNU program allowing to encrypt arbitrary TCP connections inside Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).

http://www.stunnel.org

It's very UNIX-y. One great tool for one simple task.

Comment: stunnel + nc would work, I suppose.  Good thought.

Answer (score 3):

Ask the prof or TA for assistance.  You would never try to do HTTPS over netcat in the real world (`openssl s_client` would be my first-line tool of choice, but there are other options) so the chances of finding the "right" answer that the prof wants by asking people in the real world is low.  I'd probably go over all the slides/notes from the lectures; typically these sorts of "impossible" questions are actually answered in the lectures, and asked just to see who is actually paying attention in class.